# Achieve exact control of scale and offset of UIImage in UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimageview

I currently have a UIImageView with an image loaded inside with the contentMode being set to scaleAspectFill. Is there a way to specify an exact section of the image to show instead of the default center, or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Swift Code:

```
basketballImage = UIImageView()     

basketballImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
basketballImage.clipsToBounds = true
basketballImage.image = UIImage(named: "Basketball")
```

**Original Image**
[image: Original Image]

**Desired Result**
[image: Desired Result]

**Failed Example 1:**  With `contentMode = .scaleAspectFill`
[image: Failed Example 1: With <code>contentMode = .scaleAspectFill</code>]

**Failed Example 2:**  With `contentMode = .top`
[image: Failed Example 2: With <code>contentMode = .top</code>]

Comment: you can crop image by coordinate and set to imageview

Answer (score 1):

There's no way for iOS to know what you really want since your scaling is arbitrary.

You can effectively crop (zoom-in) by setting the `contentScaleFactor` property. Aspect-fit is unrelated to your goal.

Now, the arbitrary vertical offset requires an affine transform, but only works with a *container* `UIView` to maintain the layout. You have to transform the entire `UIImageView` frame within its parent (unless you want to get very fancy and override the `draw` method or re-implement UIImageView with an affine-transform hook).

I achieved roughly what you want by installing that image at 2x resolution and using:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let offset: CGFloat = 120.0
    let scale: CGFloat = 3.0

    /* imageView is a *child* of imageContainer and constrained to be exactly the same size and position */
    imageContainer.clipsToBounds = true

    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "basketball")
    imageView.contentMode = .center
    imageView.contentScaleFactor = scale
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: offset)
}
```

It's harder than I'd like, what with another layer of nesting, but `UIImageView` is just not that sophisticated.